# htaccess rewrite not working for images

Tags: php, .htaccess

Appraciate any help anyone can give with this,

I have an old url structure of: products/category(category is dynamic and only used as an example) and i'm trying to change to category/products, to do this I used

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products index.php?category=$1
```

This is working however problem is my images are stored as images/products/image and the rule is writing all my image links,

I've tried:

```
RewriteRule ^images/products/(.*) images/products/$1
```

just to rewrite images but it doesn't seam to be working

my htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteRule ^images/products/(.*) images/products/$1

RewriteRule ^(.*)/products index.php?category=$1
```

Thanks in advance,

Dan

Answer (score 0):

The easiest would be to add a rule to not rewrite any paths of existing directories and files (your images...).

You can do that by adding these rules before your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)/products index.php?category=$1
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation for your code?

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen's answer works as well, but you can also specify a rule as an end point

```
RewriteRule ^images/products/(.*) images/products/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/products index.php?category=$1
```

The '[L]' should prevent the second rule from being parsed as the first rule should work as expected.